# Understanding the proof for consistency of the OLS estimator

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, econometrics, consistency

In my econometrics lecture we discussed the consistency of the OLS estimator ($\hat{\beta} \overset{P}{\rightarrow}\beta)$ and I don't understand why it holds that $(X'X)^{-1}=\Big(\frac{X'X}{N}\Big)^{-1}$.
In general, the OLS estimator can be written as
$$\hat\beta=\beta+(X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon$$
Now, we know that $X'X$ does not converge to anything, because for $n\rightarrow\infty$, all entries of the matrix are infinite sums. By applying the weak law of large numbers we can derive  the results that $\frac{1}{N}X'X\overset{P}{\rightarrow}E(X'X)\equiv Q_{XX}$, which is a nonsingular matrix. This basically tells us that each entry is converging to its expected value.

To proof consistency, we must show that $plim(\hat\beta)=\beta$.
Thus, we get the following
\begin{split}
plim(\hat\beta)&=plim(\beta)+plim((X'X)^{-1})plim(X'\epsilon)\\
&=\beta + \Big(plim\Big(\frac{1}{N}X'X\Big)\Big)^{-1}plim\Big(\frac{1}{N}X'\epsilon\Big)\\
&=\beta +(Q_{XX})^{-1}plim\Big(\frac{1}{N}X'\epsilon\Big)
\end{split}
where $\hat\beta$ is consistent if $plim\Big(\frac{1}{N}X'\epsilon\Big)=0$ holds (exogeneity assumption).
So far so good. However I do not understand the reasoning why we can write that $$plim\Big(\frac{1}{N}X'\epsilon\Big) = plim(X'\epsilon)$$
or $$plim\Big(\frac{1}{N}X'X\Big)=plim(X'X)$$
What is the intuition and reasoning behind these steps?

Comment: After your "thus we get the following," second line, the N's cancel. They are *not* saying that (1/N)X'X  = X'X.

Comment: Because (1/N X'X)^-1 = N (X'X)^-1 and this eleminates the second fraction? @BigBendRegion

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!